# Android "Wireless Display" Intent Action

Tags: android, android-intent

A device running Android 4.2 reportedly has a "Wireless Display" option accessible from the Status Bar. Is there an Intent Action associated with that can be used to take the user to that Activity? If so, what is it?

The reason I ask is that a client has a kiosk-type launcher app and would like to be able to block out the user from accessing that setting page. We do this for the WiFi Settings option by putting an Intent Filter on the Activity tag in the Manifest like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So what's the action for the "Wireless Display" setting? I can't seem to find it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code for android.provider.Settings I found:

```
    public static final String ACTION_WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS =
        "android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS";
```

But it's shame that this wasn't listed in the developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) (at least at the time of this posting).

Comment: +1 for a great answer. Its working for most of the devices but Samsung...For Samsung 4.2 or 4.2+ it does not work at all. 
Any idea what should be correct way of launching the same settings for Samsung devices.

Any idea? any help in this regard is appreciated in advance.

Comment: @Vinay Thanks for the upvote. Off the top of my head, I don't know how to solve the issue for Samsung devices. You should consider opening up a new question if you cannot find your answer. Have a great day.